# Back Button not Responding in UrhoSharp

Tags: android, xamarin, urhosharp

I have create an Activity which has a UrhoSharp surface as;

```
SDLSurface surface = UrhoSurface.CreateSurface(this, typeof(UrhoLayer), appOptions);
```

Now back button is not Responding. I tried overriding onBackPressed(), but this function is not called when I press back button. How to make the back button work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by catching the back button press in DispatchKeyEvent. Not a very satisfactory solution, but it works:

```
    public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == KeyEventActions.Up && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Back)
        {
            OnBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        if (!UrhoSurface.DispatchKeyEvent(e))
            return false;
        return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
    }
```

Comment: It works!! Thanks. Now i have a new problem. After pressing back when i open the activity again UrhoSurface does not load. A black screen appears in place of UrhoSurface view and nothing happens. How to solve this??

Comment: I haven't experienced that, so I would guess that's not an issue with UrhoSharp, and that the problem lies somewhere else in the app logic.